# Accessing variable from other script

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, permissions, unityscript

How do I call a variable from other script components?

```
mirror.transform.position = cop.GetComponent("AI_Car").mirrorPos;
```

It seems that the public variable `carPos` declared in the script `AI-Car-script` cannot be accessed:

```
'mirrorPos' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.
```

Comment: Is it called `carPos` or `mirrorPos`? Sounds like you want to get `carPos`, but you're getting `mirrorPos` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things:

1) I work in C#, so I may be wrong about this, but I think you have to get the component and THEN get the variable.  For example:

```
var otherScript: OtherScript = GetComponent("AI_CAR"); 
var newPosition = otherScript.mirrorPos;
```

2) I think it's best practice to make a temporary variable and then access it.  So in the above example, I would then change mirror.transform.position like this:

```
mirror.transform.position = newPosition;
```

Obviously it's not not always great to work in vars (sometimes it is, that's an entirely different conversation) but this is just a simple pseudocode example.  Hope this helps!

EDIT: [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html) are the docs

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it to the right type:

```
mirror.transform.position = ((AI_Car)cop.GetComponent("AI_Car")).mirrorPos;
mirror.transform.position = cop.GetComponent<AI_Car>().mirrorPos;
```

Anyway, the best is to make an `AI_Car` property, then get it on start, so you can simply read it anywhere in the class by `aiCar.mirrorPos` or similar.

Comment: Aw, I meant `C#`, did not touch `Javascript` yet.