# C# Unity - Trying to access a variable from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to pass a variable between a script in unity, and all of the questions previously posted seem to not help, if anything have just confused this issue more than it was intended to be.

My issue is, I have a integer named count in my PlayerController Script, and the variable of count is needed in another script called BounceObject to be used within an if statement to compare against.

This is my Player controller script, with some parts of the code missing.

```
public int count;

void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString (); 
    if (count >= 12)
    {
        winText.text = "You have won!";
    }
}
```

This is the script that I am trying to access the variable of count in, named BounceObject

```
public PlayerController script;
void Start()
 { 
    script = getComponent<PlayerController>();
 }

void Update()
 {

if (script.count >= 8)
{
    #Do Stuff here...
}

 }
```

I am not sure if I have made a mistake within my code or not. For reference the BounceObject Script is only found in a prefab which I then import into my game. The integer of count will also change so it is needed to be updated in the BounceObject script when it is changed in PlayerController.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the `PlayerController` a component of the same game object to which `BounceObject` is attached?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing variable from other script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311674/accessing-variable-from-other-script)

Comment: IF you use GetComponent, you MUST NOT mark the variable "public".  IF you mark the variable "public" you MUST NOT use GetComponent.  (if you mark it public, you must DRAG IT IN THE EDITOR to the slot - you know)?

Comment: INCREDIBLY FULL ANSWER: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35555776/294884

Comment: @Taelsin No it is not in the same game object

Comment: @Robertgold Note that c# is case-sensitive, so `getComponent` is invalid even if the script was on the same object.

Comment: @JoeBlow Normally I would agree with you, but the linked duplicate had issues both in the question and in the answer making it unclear. Your answer in your second linked post was amazing, but didn't answer this particular question. For clarity I'd prefer to keep this here.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `PlayerController` is on a separate object than your `BounceObject` script, you will need to specify which game object you want to get a component from. If you give your player object a tag that only it will have you can do this:

```
public PlayerController script;
void Start() { 
    script = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player1").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to use different methods of getting the player game object before getting its `PlayerController` script.

References I used: [FindWithTag](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) and [GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: please please, do not answer million-times duplicates

Comment: @Taelsin How does this work for Prefabs? Does it work just the same?

Comment: @Robertgold It should work the same for prefabs. Think of prefabs as templates for game objects

Comment: Will test this later, will report what happens if anything goes wrong!

Comment: This will work as for Starters. But soon, you might want to use a List to convey your objects and select from them. Findwithid or Findwithtag is "Very Slow".