# Access component from another script

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im using unity and I have Im trying to access a script called `Outline` on my parent object. I need to disable and enable the script `Outline` from another script called `Destroyable`. I know theres a ton of tutorials out there and other questions asked but it always seems to not be able to find it.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destroyable : MonoBehaviour
{
    Outline myScript;
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        myScript = gameObject.GetComponent<Outline>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Unity - Trying to access a variable from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657376/c-sharp-unity-trying-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script)

Comment: @AliKanat Its not

Comment: Actually it is. Also it looks like you already accessed `myScript`. What is the problem then?

Comment: are `Destroyable` and `Outline` on the same object? and yes what exactly is the point of trouble?

Comment: @derHugo Yes they are

Comment: @AliKanat Im trying to access a script which is on the parent called Outline. It gives me an error and says Outline could not be found

Comment: You said the components were both on the same object, but then you said `Outline` is on the parent. Are the components on the same object (not same hierarchy), or are they on different objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are on the same object than

```c#
myScript = GetComponent<Outline>();
```

should already give you the reference you want.

Otherwise if you say it is on the parent object than you should instead use

```c#
myScript = transform.parent.GetComponent<Outline>();
```

or [GetComponentInParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html) (only if the component is enabled and the GameObject active on Start)

```c#
myScript = GetComponentInParent<Outline>();
```

---

Even better (if possible) would be you make it a [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)

```c#
[SerializeField] private Outline myScript;
```

and directly reference it via the Inspector than you don't have to use `GetComponent` at all. Drag&Drop the according `GameObject` in the field it automatically gets the according component reference.

---

In order to then enable or disable it simply set [MonoBehaviour.enabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html)

```c#
myScript.enabled = true; // or false
```

Answer (score 0):

If its on your parent object then:

```
myScript = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Outline>();
```

Other good Solution(cos performance is not critical here) by Hugo:

```
myScript = gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Outline()>;
```

Not in unity enviroment but i think in the second case `gameObject` is redundant.

Comment: My bad i forgot the parent property out from the code, and get component in aprent is a good solution too ill include it

Comment: `gameObject` is actually redundant since `Transform` is of type `Component` which also has an implementation of `GetComponent`/`GetComponentInParent` so it can use that one instead.