# How to call a function is a script from another script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to call a function I have to spawn an object from another script when I collide with an object. Here is the code in the first script

```
public void Spawn() {
   //My code here
}
```

and here is my other script

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) {
   //I want to call the script here
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You make a public property with the type of the other script. You set the gameobject that contains the script either in (1) inspector if it exists in editor or (2) at runtime. If the method in the other script is public then it will be invokable. However, something tells me this question is already answered. The title could also use some work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Unity - Trying to access a variable from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657376/c-sharp-unity-trying-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Get GetComponent to get it.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) 
{
        //I want to call the script here
    if(coll)
    {
        WhatYouWant gotit = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<WhatYouWant>();
        if(gotit)
        {
            //call some function with it.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply attach the script to another gameobject and then call it via the Script
eg: Gameobject 'test' has the new spawn script

Your Code in onTriggerEnter:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) {
    GameObject targetObj = GameObject.Find("test").GetComponent<ScriptName>().Spawn();
}
```

Be aware that this is not an ideal method as you should not search for Gameobjects during runtime. It would be better if you would attach the second Gameobject via a public GameObject variable or, if you have to search for it, do it in the start Method and save it to a variable.